# Executing a command after ECS + FARGATE container startup

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, redis, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I'm deploying a Redis instance to an ECS container, running with FARGATE. Here is a sample of my container definition:

```
[
    {
        "name": "redis",
        "image": "redis",
        "restart": "always",
        "portMappings": [
            {"containerPort": 6379,
            "hostPort": 6379}
        ],
        "healthcheck": {
            "Command": ["/bin/sh", "redis-cli", "SMEMBERS", "clientSet","|", "grep", "39e24s4"],
            "Interval": 30,
            "Timeout": 10,
            "Retries": 5
        },
        "logConfiguration": {
            "logDriver": "awslogs",
                "options": {
                   "awslogs-group": "redis-log-group",
                   "awslogs-region": "us-east-1",
                   "awslogs-stream-prefix": "redis"
                }
        }
    }
]
```

My health-check looks for a pre-instantiated client.
What I'm trying to do is run the below commands right *after* the redis image is instantiated, checking out the docs, the 'command' and 'entrypoint' fields haven't been useful since they run the provided command instead of instantiating the redis image.

Is there any field I can use, or anything I can do to perform such a task in an automated way (without using ECS Exec)?

```
redis-cli SADD clientSet <client-id>
redis-cli SMEMBERS clientSet
```

Comment: Did you ever manage to get this working? I am stuck with the same issue.

Answer (score 3):

You don't want to use `ECS exec` neither can you use a combination of AWS Systems Manager (SSM) and `docker exec` since fargate doesn't allow `docker exec`.

However, you can leverage `COMMAND` parameter when ECS is starting the docker container. Inside the container definition parameters, under [`Environment`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task_definition_parameters.html#container_definition_environment), you can specify the `CMD` command that you want to run instead of the one specified in the image via Dockerfile. This will be equivalent to:

```
docker run -p 6379:6379 redis /bin/bash -c "redis-server --daemonize yes && sleep 1 && redis-cli SADD clientSet client1 && redis-cli save && redis-cli shutdown && redis-server"
```

Let's see one by one what we're doing here:

1. `redis-server --daemonize yes` - *start redis server in background*
2. `sleep 1` - *wait for 1 sec; this is to wait for server to start completely*
3. `redis-cli SADD clientSet client1` - *add the data to redis set in memory*
4. `redis-cli save` - *persist data to disk*
5. `redis-cli shutdown` - *stop server started previously*
6. `redis-server` - *start the server normally*

I would also recommend adding a small grace period before the health check starts. This can be specified using `startPeriod` parameter inside `healthcheck` object. So, our new container definition would look like:

```
[
  {
    "name": "redis",
    "image": "redis",
    "restart": "always",
    "portMappings": [
      {
        "containerPort": 6379,
        "hostPort": 6379
      }
    ],
    "healthcheck": {
      "command": ["/bin/sh", "redis-cli", "SMEMBERS", "clientSet","|", "grep", "39e24s4"],
      "interval": 30,
      "timeout": 10,
      "retries": 5,
      "startPeriod": 10
    },
    "logConfiguration": {
      "logDriver": "awslogs",
      "options": {
        "awslogs-group": "redis-log-group",
        "awslogs-region": "us-east-1",
        "awslogs-stream-prefix": "redis"
      }
    },
    "command": [
        "/bin/bash -c \"redis-server --daemonize yes && sleep 1 && redis-cli SADD clientSet rhl && redis-cli save && redis-cli shutdown && redis-server\""
    ]
  }
]
```